# Rasterization (Vector to Raster) in QGIS overwrites Maxima values of the vector

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, spatial-statistics, rasterization

I am working on macroseismic intensity maps in QGIS 3.30. My data are in the form of a point vector. In this case, each point has an attribute corresponding to the maximum intensity which was experienced at the respective point (in this case between 1-5).

Basically is what I am trying to do is create a raster from this point layer via the Rasterize (Vector to Raster) function,so that each raster pixel (between 1x1 and 2.5x2.5 km in size) is defined by the maximum intensity of a point which lies within the pixel.

However, due to the math behind the rasterize function and our high data point density, our maximum values are often overwritten/statistically over powered by the neighboring data points of lesser intensity. As a result, the created raster does not have any maxima corresponding to the number 5 although these are present in the data set/attribute table of the point layer.

How do I rasterize my point layer, so that the raster pixels are defined by the maximum value found within the raster pixel?

Comment: Simple rasterization is not really suited for such tasks, what you need here is interpolation. I suggest you look up some literature on the topic, most likely there are already some good practices for interpolating seismic data. Then you can ask here how to realize your chosen method in QGIS, if neccessary.